# Python tkinter scrollbar handle not accurately represented

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I've created a scrollbar widget in tkinter and connected it to a Listbox widget. I can scroll, use the arrows and drag the handle up and down perfectly fine. When I let go however, the handle teleports to the top of the scrollbar, and I don't understand why.
Here's a gif showing the problem:

[image]

And here's my code

```
self.chattHistoryScrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.upperFrame)
self.chattHistoryScrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'NSE')
self.chattHistoryScrollbar.config(command = self.chattHistory.yview)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: You missed the line `self.chattHistory.config(yscrollcommand=self.chattHistoryScrollbar.set)`.